# Is there a way to draw a dotted curve as a polyline in mkmapview?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkmapview

I'm currently using [curvyRoute](https://github.com/seatcode/curvyRoute) library to draw curvy poly lines . It draws the poly line as a normal line but I want poly line to be dotted . The library is using addquadcurve to draw curvy lines . Is there any way to make it as dotted lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can draw dotted line by adding this style.

```
polyline = MGLPolyline(coordinates: mapCoordinates, count: UInt(mapCoordinates.count))

source = MGLShapeSource(identifier: "line", shape: polyline, options: nil)
style.addSource(source)

let dottedLayer = MGLLineStyleLayer(identifier: "dotted-line-layer", source: source)
dottedLayer.lineColor = NSExpression(forConstantValue: UIColor.darkGray)
dottedLayer.lineWidth = NSExpression(forConstantValue: 4.0)
dottedLayer.lineCap = NSExpression(forConstantValue: "round")
dottedLayer.lineDashPattern = NSExpression(forConstantValue: [0.25, 1.5])
```

If we are using MKMapView then we can use this,

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
   guard let polyline = overlay as? MKPolyline else {
       fatalError("Not a MKPolyline")
   }

   let renderer = MKPolylineRenderer(polyline: polyline)

   renderer.strokeColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.2, green: 0.5, blue: 0.77, alpha: 1)
   renderer.lineWidth = 6
   renderer.lineDashPattern = [0, 10]

   return renderer
}
```

Comment: Where does a guy named `MGLPolyline` come from?  `MGLShapeSource`?

Comment: @ElTomato I have updated my answer for MKMapView. Thanks for notiying.